# preg_replace word with exception

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have read quite a few posts here and on other sites in order to create the semi-working swear word filter with `preg_replace` as below:

```
function swearwords($word){
    $word = preg_replace('/\bwwww.badword.com\b/', '', $word); //do not remove \b //to add more copy and put word down
    $word = preg_replace('/\bwww.badword.com\b/', '', $word); //do not remove \b //to add more copy and put word down
    $word = preg_replace('/\bbadword\b/', '', $word); //do not remove \b //to add more copy and put word down
    //$word = preg_replace('/\bimg.badword``\b/', '', $word); //do not remove \b //to add more copy and put word down
    return $word;
}
```

This is working but I want to allow instances of img.badword

So where "`badword`" has .img before it, I want to allow that use

Comment: `'/\b[^i][^m][^g][^.]badword\b/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution with *'negative lookbehind'* assertion:

```
...
$word = preg_replace('/\b(?<!img\.)badword\b/', '', $word);
...
```

You may also try the following all-in-one replacement:

```
function swearwords($word){
    $word = preg_replace('/\b(w{3,4}\.)*(?<!img\.)badword(\.com)*\b/', '', $word);
    return $word;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php

Comment: All-in-one solution brilliant. Thank you

Comment: One more twist, I need to allow both img.badword and imgmgr.badword

Comment: here it is: `preg_replace('/\b(w{3,4}\.)*(?<!img\.|imgmgr\.)badword(\.com)*\b/iu', '', $word)`

Comment: Thank you very much, the novice I am , I was trying ('/\b(w{3,4}\.)*(?<!img\.)(?<!imgmgr\.)badword(\.com)*\b/',